# When completion of locally compact length space is locally compact?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, gn.general-topology, reference-request

As far as I know the answer to the question:
"Is it true that a completion of a locally compact length space is locally compact?" - Negative.

Does anybody know some metric and/or topological conditions for locally compact length space $(X,d)$ such that its completion $\bar{X}$ is locally compact?

Comment: I'm intrigued: I've never heard of a "length space", can you give a reference?

Comment: Dmitri Burago; Yuri Burago; and Sergei Ivanov - A Course in Metric Geometry. Chapter 2.
(length space = space with intrinsic metric)

Comment: Andrew, the term originates, as far as I know, from a now out-of-print book in French by Gromov et al. Luckily, an updated and translated version is now available: http://books.google.com/books?id=HWm-z3VU9eAC&lpg=PP1&ots=fOgfbB6IwW&dq=metric%20structures%20gromov&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Would you happen to have a counter-example verifying the negative answer to your question?

Comment: Consider the universal cover of the punctured Euclidean plane with the (incomplete) induced Riemannian metric. Its universal cover is a length space but its metric completion is not locally compact

Comment: @ Paul Siegel: I have only reference to the book Martin R. Bridson, André Haefliger - Metric spaces of non-positive curvature. page 34. "... (4) Prove that there exists a geodesic metric space which is locally compact but whose completion is neither geodesic nor locally compact (Hint: Consider the induced path metric space on the following subset of the Euclidean plane: $(0,1]\times \{0\}\cup(0,1]\times \{1\}\cup \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{1/n\}\times [0,1]$.)

Comment: Ivan, will you give a more detailed definition? I.e. what do you mean here by "space" and "intrinsic metric".

Comment: @ Pietro Majer: $(X,d)$ - metric space, $d$ is intrinsic metric if for any two points $x,y\in X$ the distance $d(x,y)=\inf_{\gamma}\{L(\gamma)\}$, where $\gamma$ is path connecting $x,y$. (See book Dmitri Burago; Yuri Burago; and Sergei Ivanov - A Course in Metric Geometry.) 

Comment: @Pietro Majer, length space is of course in wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric

Answer (score 2):

A necessary and sufficient condition (but I do not feel satisfied with that) for the locally compact length space $X$ to have a locally compact completion is that there exists some $r>0$ such that each ball of radius $r$ in $X$ is totally bounded.

In fact, if the condition holds closed balls of radius $r/2$ in $\overline{X}$ are compact.
On the other hand, suppose that $\overline{X}$ is locally compact. Then, as it is a complete length space, it is proper (this is called the Hopf-Rinow Theorem in the book by Bridson and Haefliger). This should imply that balls of any radius in $X$ are totally bounded.

The main reason why I am not satisfied with it is that the proof that the condition is sufficient does not use that $X$ is a length space, so this is not really the answer to what you asked. I thought it might be relevant, anyway...

Comment: Unfortunately it is not useful. My fruitless search in the Internet give me only new (for me) definition -  A metric space is said to be locally precompact space if its completion is locally compact. Article
"Detecting Hilbert manifolds among isometrically homogeneous metric space" Taras O.Banakh and Dusan Repovs http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.4205